# My CGI script cookie set and get

Tags: perl, cookies, cgi, setcookie

I have a site on CGI and working fine yesterday but suddenly its cookie stop working. I am unable to set cookie and get cookie in my script. below is my code.

To set cookie

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use CGI::Carp qw (fatalsToBrowser);
use CGI;
require "cookie.lib";
&SetCookies('V', $EncUID);
```

To get cookie

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use CGI::Carp qw (fatalsToBrowser);
use CGI;
require "cookie.lib";
&GetCookies();
my $UID = $Cookies{"V"};
```

Please Help me regarding this.

Comment: I assume you remove that 'fatalsToBrowser' when you move that code onto your production web server.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Whoa, it's suddenly like 199x all over. Replace `cookie.lib` with [`CGI::Cookie`](http://p3rl.org/CGI%3a%3aCookie).

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use CGI::Carp qw(fatalsToBrowser);
use CGI;
use CGI::Cookie qw();

print CGI::header(-cookie => [CGI::Cookie->new(-name => 'V',-value => $EncUID)]);
```

---

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use CGI::Carp qw(fatalsToBrowser);
use CGI;
use CGI::Cookie qw();

my %cookies = CGI::Cookie->fetch;
my $UID = $cookies{'V'}->value;
```

Comment: Thaks Daxim thanks for your help. 

My problem was fixed i have replace my cookie.lib with new file current file is too old and now works fine